# Using Ext.loader with Ext.application

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

How does one enable the loader when using ext.application?

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'App',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});
        Ext.Loader.setPath('App','js/App');
        Ext.create('App.view.SomeView');//this blows up in my face
    }
});
```

This is what I'm currently doing, and its trying to open:

```
./App/view/SomeView
```

instead of

```
./js/App/view/SomeView
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add *appFolder* like this:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});
Ext.application({
    name: 'App',
    appFolder: 'js/App', // maybe '/js/App'

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('App.view.SomeView');
    }
});
```

Maybe your code would work too, but you have to move your loader config out of launch() method because it fires after application is created and I guess that causes your problem.